# Can I put multiple ListArrays in different colums of the same h:datatable?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a form where I have to fill 3 columns of a table with data. Each of these columns has an ArrayList from a backing bean attached. Each of the ArrayLists holds the same number of instances of the same type "LabValue". Each LabValue has a name ("Parameter") and a unit ("Einheit") but I need both columns only once for the first datatable (picture below).

Since a `h:datatable` can only hold one List until now I solved the problem by putting three datatables in one row of a `h:panelgrid` as shown in the picture below:

[image: Form with three datatables in a one-row panelgrid]

This works fine but we have some trouble with our tests in different browsers: Sometimes we have a vertical offset between Datatable1 on the one hand and Datatable2&3 on the other hand (e.g. Chrome and Firefox work fine; Safari not).

E.g. Safari renders the header of datatable 2 and 3 in four lines and datatable one in three lines (not shown in picture). This will cause an offset.

So the best way would be to have them in one single datatable and finally get rid of the offset.

Is there a way to do this in JSF 2.0 without introducing a new class holding all three lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much better to create a new class, but it can be done.

See http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Parameters_In_EL_Functions

In the jsf do something like this:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.myList}" var="labValue">
    <h:column><h:outputText value="#{labValue.label}" /></h:column>
    <h:column><h:outputText value="#{myBean.secondList[myBean.firstListIndex[labValue]].label}" /></h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

In java:

```
class MyWrapper implements Map {
     ...
     public Integer getIndex(Object firstRowElement) {
         int index = firstList.indexOf(firstRowElement);
         return index;
     }
     public Object get(Object obj) {
         return getIndex(obj);
     }
}
public Map getFirstListIndex() {
    return myWrapper;
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you. I think a bit of extra code in my backing bean is not to avoid. I will give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this in JSF 2.0
>   without introducing a new class
>   holding all three lists?

No, there isn't - and why would that be so important to avoid anyway?

Comment: Not so important, just wanted to avoid the overhead of a new class in order to keep the managed bean "clean" since the lists are from entity classes.